# XML response in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, response

I have a flash file that displays the server respone on screen. The respone is in XML format.
When I use this code: `statusText.text = xmlResponse;` I get result on screen like

> %3%20xml

etc.
What 's wrong with that? I tried the methods `toString()` and `text()` but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your string may be "URL encoded".
Try the unescape() function.

Comment: The unescape method I think doesn't wotk in AS3

Comment: Sorry, I used his recomendation and this method
`var readableString:String = unescape(xmlResponse).replace(/\+/g, " ");`
and everything worked! In AS3 unescape works different than in AS2